# Rotación de botón al clickear JavaScript, CSS, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentando rotar una botón con una imagen en 360 grados cada vez que se clickee con un delay de 2.5 segundos de retraso en cada click, pero solo rota 1 vez y el retraso en milisegundos también cuenta en el primer click cuando quiero que cuente a partir del segundo.

```js
var millisecondsToWait = 2500;
var firstClickRefresh = true;

function refreshBtn(){
    var i = 0
    if(firstClickRefresh = true){
        for(i;i<1;i++) {
            (function () {
              setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('btnRefresh').classList.add('rotate');
                firstClickRefresh = false;
              }, 100);
            })(i);
          }
    }else{
        for(i;i<1;i++) {
            (function () {
              setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('btnRefresh').classList.add('rotate');
              }, millisecondsToWait);
            })(i);
          }
    }
}
```

```css
.rotate {
    -webkit-animation:spin 2.5s ease-in-out;
     -moz-animation:spin 2.5s ease-in-out;
     animation:spin 2.5s ease-in-out;
 }
 @-moz-keyframes spin {
     100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes spin {
     100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
 }
 @keyframes spin { 
     100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } 
 }
```

```html
<button id="btnRefresh" class="btnRefreshClass" onclick="refreshBtn()" width="200px" height="250px"></button>
```

Comment: Hay un problema de partida con esto... no esta la funcion que el boton quiere llamar.

Comment: Disculpa corrijo el codigo javascript, debe de ser refreshBtn

Comment: Si por favor corrigela, necesitas tener un [mre] al menos para este caso.

Comment: Ya esta corregido 

Comment: Bien, ahora hace falta setupFunc()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que veo es que le das la propiedad de giro con el botón, pero no lo quitas del botón, lo que puedes hacer es calcular el tiempo de giro del botón, para después quitarlo de el.

```js
function refreshBtn(){
    let rotacion= (360/100) * 2.5; // calculo el tiempo de rotacion
    setTimeout(()=>{
    document.getElementById('btnRefresh').classList.add('rotate');
    }, 100);
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
    document.getElementById('btnRefresh').classList.remove('rotate');
    }, rotacion);

}
```

```css
.rotate {
    -webkit-animation:spin 2.5s ease-in-out;
     -moz-animation:spin 2.5s ease-in-out;
     animation:spin 2.5s ease-in-out;
 }
 @-moz-keyframes spin {
     100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes spin {
     100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
 }
 @keyframes spin { 
     100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } 
 }
```

```html
<button id="btnRefresh" class="btnRefreshClass" onclick="refreshBtn()">girar</button>
```

---

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! otra consulta, como podria hacer para darle un delay? por ejemplo que al clickear denuevo espere 2.5 segundos mas cuando termine de rotar

Answer (score 1):

Puedes añadirle una clase `toRotate` a los elementos que quieres rotar, puedes aumentar la duración de `transition` si quieres un *spin* más suave

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".toRotate").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    el.classList.toggle("rotate");
  });
});
```

```css
.toRotate {
  transition:2.5s;
  -webkit-transition:2.5s;
  -moz-transition:2.5s;
  -o-transition:2.5s;
}

.rotate {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
  transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="toRotate">Rotate</button>
<img class="toRotate" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/01/26/09/45/sunbird-5950943_960_720.jpg" height="200" width="200">
```

Usando `classList.toggle`, activamos y desactivamos clases de manera que

- Si una clase existe, la elimina
- Si una clase no existe, la añade

---

Puedes hacerlo con CSS solamente también, usando el selector `:focus`, pero solo funciona con botones

```css
.toRotate {
  transition:2.5s;
  -webkit-transition:2.5s;
  -moz-transition:2.5s;
  -o-transition:2.5s;
}

.toRotate:focus {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
  transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="toRotate">Rotate</button>
```

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, el document.QuerySelectorAll() va dentro de una funcion de javascript?